# How to use NSScanner to parse .ics file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, icalendar, nsscanner

Could someone please show how i could parse a ics file using NSScanner? (Iphone App)

e.g: if the .ics file was at this URL http://www.ibz.com/data/12345.ics (not a real URL!!!)

1. How would i firstly save the .ics
   file into my iphone app
2. and then secondly how would i parse
       the .ics file using NSScanner??

Please provide code examples..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Code examples to do this completely and well would be quite extensive, and SO isn't the place for large sample applications. With that in mind, the general solutions would be:

1. Use a [NSURLRequest](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to get an HTTP connection to download the file; store it as an NSData object built during delegate calls from the NSURLConnection. Once it's completely downloaded, convert it to an NSString for parsing. The [URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE) has a number of examples - look for NSURLConnection and asynchronous requests.
2. To parse the .ics file (which at this point is available as an NSString), you'll first need to figure out the expected format of the file. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) seems to have a couple examples of how .ics files store data. Basically you'll want to go through and scan strings separated by the various separators the file format uses (looks to be mostly colons).

If you have more specific questions, you'll probably get much more specific answers - give it a shot and ask more if you get stuck!

Comment: Thank you Tim. I am also behind something like this. To parse a .ics file. I have downloaded it and stored in Document directory. Is there any chance "UIDocumentInteractionController" could be used to open/import a .ics file. In iOS 4.2 release notes they have given like that. But I am unable to open the file/even at least preview it. Please help if any update. Anyway I will try using NSScanner and let you know the updates.