# Using a Calendar in my iPhone Application to Publish Events

Tags: iphone, xcode, events, calendar, icalendar

I am trying to build an application that shows a Calendar with events that are published by the owner of the application. That is, users that download the application will be able to see the dates of special events and add them to their own calendar.

Is there a way to do this, or is the only option to do an XML Parsing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UIKit.framework` has no API for a UI calendar.

There are open source projects for UI calendars like [Tapku](https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary).

Tapku's `TKCalendarMonthView` mimics the Calender.app UI preloaded on iOS.

Using a combination of the Tapku library, XML or JSON parsing, and magic you could fetch special events from your webserver and add them to Tapku's `TKCalendarMonthView` to achieve your goal.

Thanks,

-David

Answer (score 2):

**API for UI calendar**

In addition to Tapku bobbypage referenced here is also the KLCalendarView which attempts to look somewhat like Calendar.app (Search for it, I'm out of hyperlinks).

**API for adding events to a user's calendar**

Check out Apple's [EventKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EventKitFrameworkRef/_index.html) reference. It allows for adding static and recurring events.
Here is a good [video](http://www.wonderhowto.com/how-to-use-event-kit-ui-apple-ios-4-sdk-395865/) tutorial on how to use event kit.

**XML or JSON parsing**

Depends on the source of the calendar. Here is another SO question about paring ics files on the iPhone.

[How to use NSScanner to parse .ics file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111919/how-to-use-nsscanner-to-parse-ics-file)

Answer (score 0):

There is no UI provided by Apple for this task, but [EventKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EventKitFrameworkRef/_index.html) may help you with the logic for your app.